# The sins of the oppressed are loaded unto the oppressor?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation

> Narrated Abu Huraira:
>
> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "Whoever has oppressed another person concerning his reputation or anything else, he should beg him to forgive him before the Day of Resurrection when there will be no money (to compensate for wrong deeds), but if he has good deeds, those good deeds will be taken from him according to his oppression which he has done, and if he has no good deeds, **the sins of the oppressed person will be loaded on him**." (Sahih al-Bukhari 2449 Book 46, Hadith 10; bold emphasis mine)

I'm confused, is everyone accountable for his/her own sins or not? Doesn't this contradict the principle that none will bear the burden of another?

The sins belonged to the oppressed. The oppressor will bear the sins of the oppressed. Hence the oppressor will be punished from the sins he didn't commit. I don't get it.

Comment: The hadith speaks about what one should do **before** the day of resurrection. As if one didn't one may earn the sins of the person one has wronged in dunya and that is widely addressed in other ahadith and in the qur'an too.

Comment: In the Qur'an and hadith, it is stated that one will be held accountable for causing people to sin, **without the sins and punishment committed by those people being diminished**. Here in this Hadith it doesn't suggest that. It clearly states that the sins of the oppressed will be dimished and loaded unto the oppressor. That's like substitutionary atonement. Help me out.

Comment: This Hadith contradicts everything

Comment: It seems your understanding something wrong.. As we are informed that in the day of judgement after being if you had wronged somebody in dunya and your good deeds  where not enough to repay him you'd get his bad deeds instead as clearly stated in the sahih sunnah.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple brother:

Imagine if someone oppresses you by stealing £100,000 of you. On the day of judgement, that person will get the punishment that is fixed for stealing £100,000.

However, Allah is so just he will lighten your load of punishment the equivalent of stealing £100,000, and put it on him (by deleting his good deeds first and if they run out by adding to his weight of bad deeds).

In reality, he is being punished for his own sin, but the load is being taken off you since you have been oppressed.

I hope that makes sense